# Package vhdl inclusion error

Tags: include, package, vhdl

Hi guys i have the following package, defined by myself

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;

package util_pkg is
    function log2c(n : natural) return natural;
end package util_pkg;

package body util_pkg is
    function log2c(n : natural) return natural is
        variable temp    : natural := n;
            variable ret_val : natural := 0;
    begin
        while temp > 1 loop
            ret_val := ret_val + 1;
            temp = temp/2;
        end loop;       
        return ret_val;
    end function log2c;
end package body util_pkg;
```

while my design is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
use work.util_pkg.all;

entity ldz is
    generic(n : natural); --i can assume n > 1
    port(x : in std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0);
         y : out std_logic_vector(log2c(n) - 1 downto 0));
end entity ldz;

-- Example

architecture ldz_arch of ldz is

    function ldz_count(x : unsigned) return natural is
        n_ldz : natural := 0;
    begin

        for i in x'high to 0 loop
            if(x(i) = '1') then
                return x'length - i - 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return x'length - 1;
    end function ldz_count;
begin
    y <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(ldz_count(to_unsigned(x)));
end architecture ldz_arch;
```

When i try to verify the syntax with ncvhdl this is the error i get

```
unit (UTIL_PKG) not found in library (WORKLIB)
```

however such unit (package) is in the same library of the design.
the file is `util_pkg.vhd` while the design is `ldz.vhd`

What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure you compile the package before `ldz.vhd` and also make sure you compile your package into the work library by adding `-work work`.

Comment: Your log2c function is not correct. Example: n=5d=101b. It iterates 2 times and increments ret_val to 2, but log2ceil (5) is not 2, it's 3.

Comment: If x is longer than 1 bit, then this loop `for i in x'high to 0 loop` has an empty range.

Comment: And if `x'low` is not 0 you may have other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool complains because the package has not been analysed (compiled) before `ldz`. Compile it first and `ldz` next.

As mentioned in the comments, your code suffers several problems. The following code computes the log2 of a positive, rounded towards 0 or infinity:

```
function log2_down(n: positive) is
  variable res: natural := 0;
begin
  if n /= 1 then
    res := 1 + log2_down(n / 2);
  end if;
  return res;
end function log2_down;

function log2_up(n: positive) is
  variable res: natural := 0;
begin
  if n /= 1 then
    res := 1 + log2_up((n + 1) / 2);
  end if;
  return res;
end function log2_up;
```

Yes, VHDL supports recursion and most synthesisers too, at least when the number of iterations is statically computable.

The `res` variable could be avoided but it helps avoiding the warnings of some tools that warn you if the return statements of a function are all under control of a control structure. They do this because they cannot prove that the function will always return while a function shall always return. I always try to suppress the warnings such that any remaining warning is meaningful and cannot be ignored.

Declaring the parameter as `positive` is a simple way to deal with the `log2(0)` error. I always try to use the built-in features of the language to deal with errors.

With the same two principles (no warnings, let the built-in features of the language deal with errors), your leading zero counter `ldz_count` function could be written:

```
function ldz_count(x: unsigned) return natural is
  constant n: positive := x'length;
  constant v: unsigned(0 to n - 1) := x;
  variable res: natural := n;
begin
    for i in 0 to n - 1 loop
      if v(i) = '1' then
        res := i;
      end if;
  end if;
  return res;
end function ldz_count;
```

Copying the `x` parameter with a chosen bit indexing will make your function usable with any `x` parameter whatever its declaration (`7 to 35` or `9 downto 4`) as long as it is at least one bit long. This is the third principle I like: if you make something generic, make it *really* generic.

Comment: So i have to use ncvhdl with the package first? And then the same on my design?

Comment: Yes. Just like with most programming languages. Compile the dependency before the dependent.